# Ant tasks compc for air errors

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, ant, air

I'm trying to compile the SWC from the source I have writen, but for some reason I'm getting this error:

```
[compc] Error: 'flash.events:StageOrientationEvent' is undefined.
[compc]
[compc] Error: 'flash.data:EncryptedLocalStore' is undefined.
[compc]
[compc] Error: 'flash.desktop:NativeDragActions' is undefined.
[compc]
[compc] Error: 'flash.desktop:NativeDragOptions' is undefined.
[compc]
[compc] Error: 'flash.events:NativeDragEvent' is undefined.
```

and can not figure out how to fix it.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

tThe compc code:

```
<compc debug="true" target-player="10.2" optimize="true" strict="true" as3="true" compute-digest="false" output="${outputFull}">
    <include-sources dir="./" includes="**/*.as" />
<compiler.library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs" append="true">
        <include name="*"/>
</compiler.library-path>
</compc>
```

Comment: Please add the error in text to your question instead of posting a link to an external resource.

Cheers

Comment: Which AIR and which Flex version? Seems you're trying to compile a mobile project, there are also metadate related caveats with that.

Comment: I'm using flex_sdk_4.5.0.19786, and Target is 10.2,  the swc is a part of desktop application. everyhing was good until i added `EncryptedLocalStore` functionality

Comment: Having the same problem. Found a solution yet?

Comment: Have tried to add air libraries, mobile libraries, all without any result.

Comment: i did have tried it to. but also with no results. have left that part to be compiled with Flash.

but i think since here is `target-player:10.2`, should be something else, when compiling the AIR application. or need to change `compc` to something else. but have not investigated further...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, after some google-fu, I discovered compc **won't work for air component libraries!**.

Get this, you need to use acompc! Yep! Check this out: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=CommandLineTools_3.html

I've never heard of it either, and google acompc doesn't really give you much.

I can't find any documentation on an ANT task, but I found this blog post which describes how to do it with "exec-task", the build.xml is in the comment of this blog post: http://andkrup.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/flex-3-5-air-swc-ant-tasks/

**Update**
I was re-reading that blog post and noticed at the bottom this code was posted in the very last comment:

```
<compc output="${dir.build}/${ant.project.name}.swc" target-player="10.0.0">
    <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/air-config.xml" />
</compc>
```

Apparently compc just needs a different config.xml to run correctly.

Comment: same line you need to add to `<mxmlc>` to compile swf for air.

Comment: thanks! was scratching my head for a few hours till i found this :)